# Що таке "дереза"?

Tags: значення-слів

Є така  українська казка ["Коза-**дереза**"](https://kazky.org.ua/zbirky/ukrajinsjki-narodni-kazky/koza-dereza). Що таке **дереза**? В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/dereza) знаходжу:

> **ДЕРЕЗА́, и**, жін.
>
> 1. (Caragana frutex). Розгалужений кущ родини бобових, що росте в степу, по степових схилах. На плато вони [чагарникові зарості] утворені в основному дерезою (Caragana frutex) (Український ботанічний журнал, XIII, 2, 1956, 54).
> 2. (Lycium barbarum). Колючий кущ родини пасльонових, який добре вкорінюється на сухих схилах, скелях, обривах; повій звичайний. Од високої скелі.. починався рів, обсаджений густою дерезою (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 125).

Однак, це значення не зовсім підходить до даного контексту. То що ж таке **дереза**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [Етимологічному словнику, т. 2, с. 37](https://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=37) читаємо:

> **дереза** (бот.) настирлива людина; **сварлива** людина.

Отже, **коза-дереза = настирлива коза = сварлива коза**.